# How do I use LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm newbie at LINQ and I'd like to know how to use it with a database located on a remote server.

So, in other words...is there any way to tell LINQ my database's connection string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have LINQ classes generated yet? Do you get an error when you use Add New Item to add them?

Comment: Is your question about remote database vs. local database, or do you simply not know how to use LINQ to SQL at all? That would be a different set of answers, like the one from Robin Day, below.

Comment: Hi, thanks both for your quick answers.

This is the first time i'm going to use LINQ to SQL so I have no idea at all.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for saying so. Notice how I changed the subject of your question. The answers to this don't depend on SQL version or remote vs. local, so that shouldn't have been in your subject.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ScottGu's [LINQToSql tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx).  Outstanding resource to start the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

There's some great tutorials in getting started on the asp.net site.

http://www.asp.net/learn/linq-videos/

Answer (score 0):

Yes Properties/Settings.settings in a desktop app and web.config in web app